# Which SPF quantifier applies when an SPF include is used?

Tags: email, dns, email-spoofing, spf

An SPF record has several tags of which one can be the `include` tag, and the SPF record ends with a quantifier like `+`, `?`, `~` or `-`.

When an `include` tag is used, the included SPF record has it’s own SPF quantifier. Let’s call the quantifier from the included SPF record “child-quantifier”.

Does that “child-quantifier” apply on the hosts it defines only and the “parent-quantifier” on everything but the child-defined hosts? Or does the parent-quantifier always overrule all included (child-)quantifiers?

For example:

1. example1.com (let’s say parent) contains the following SPF record: 
   `v=spf1 a include:example2.com -all`
2. example2.com (let’s say child) contains the following SPF record: `v=spf1 a ip4:1.2.3.4 ?all`

Now does the `?all` (child-)quantifier or the `-all` (parent-)quantifier apply on `ip4:1.2.3.4`?

*The included SPF record might also have includes, and so it can reach a depth of multiple levels on which my question also applies.*

Comment: this might be of some help: http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax I think it might answer all of your recent SPF questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `include` mechanism the "included" SPF statement is not literally included in the original one but only the result of it is used. From [section 5.2 of RFC 7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2):

> In hindsight, the name "include" was poorly chosen.  **Only the
> evaluated result of the referenced SPF record is used**, rather than
> literally including the mechanisms of the referenced record in the
> first.  For example, evaluating a "-all" directive in the referenced
> record does not terminate the overall processing and does not
> necessarily result in an overall "fail".

This means, that the result of the "included" SPF statement is treated as a `match`, `not match` or `permerror` similar to every other SPF statement.
The standard even explicitly contains a table how the result of the "included" SPF statement affects the main statement:

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| A recursive check_host() result | Causes the "include" mechanism  |
| of:                             | to:                             |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| pass                            | match                           |
|                                 |                                 |
| fail                            | not match                       |
|                                 |                                 |
| softfail                        | not match                       |
|                                 |                                 |
| neutral                         | not match                       |
|                                 |                                 |
| temperror                       | return temperror                |
|                                 |                                 |
| permerror                       | return permerror                |
|                                 |                                 |
| none                            | return permerror                |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Translating the [documentation](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) to your example:

In the following example, the client IP is 1.2.3.4 and the current-domain is example1.com.

`v=spf1 include:example2.com -all`

If example2.com has no SPF record, the result is PermError.

Suppose example2.com's SPF record were `v=spf1 a -all`.

Look up the A record for example2.com. If it matches 1.2.3.4, return Pass.

If there is no match, other than example2.com's `-all`, the include as a whole fails to match; the eventual result is still Fail from the **outer** directive set in this example.

Trust relationships — The `include:` mechanism is meant to cross administrative boundaries. Great care is needed to ensure that `include:` mechanisms do not place domains at risk for giving SPF Pass results to messages that result from cross user forgery. Unless technical mechanisms are in place at the specified otherdomain to prevent cross user forgery, `include:` mechanisms should give a Neutral rather than Pass result. This is done by adding `?` in front of `include:`. The example above would be:

`v=spf1 ?include:example.com -all`

---

So, trust is transferred to the "child" domain (and there are mechanisms to limit that impact).